# Loading Property file to map via spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So I'm trying to learn Spring Boot and I'm completely stuck here. I'm trying to learn how to load property files and simply print the result via a servlet.

This is my `application.properties` file

```
example.mapProperty.key1=MapValue1
example.mapProperty.key2=MapValue2
```

Property Class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "example")
public class DemoProperty {

    private Map<String, String> mapProperty;

    public Map<String, String> getMapProperty() {
        return mapProperty;
    }

    public void setMapProperty(Map<String, String> mapProperty) {
        this.mapProperty = mapProperty;
    }

    }
```

Servlet Class:

```
public class HelloCountryServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HelloCountryServlet.class);

    @Autowired
    private DemoProperty demoProperty;

    public void setDemoProperty(DemoProperty demoProperty) {
            this.demoProperty = demoProperty;
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        logger.info("Logger is running");
        logger.info("demoProperty :: " + demoProperty);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        for(Entry<String, String> i : demoProperty.getMapProperty().entrySet()) {
                out.println("<h3>Property " + i.getKey() + " : " + i.getValue() + "</h3>");
        }
    }
}
```

Starter Class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootAppStarter extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootAppStarter.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAppStarter.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>SpringBootApp Maven Webapp</name>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>SpringBootApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I'm running it on Wildfly server in sts.

War structure:

```
META-INF
WEB-INF __
          |
          |_ lib
          |_ classes__
                      |
                      |_ application.properties
                      |_ class files
```

Unfortunately I'm always getting the demoProperty class as null.

Here's a part of the log:

```
0:34:15,484 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 2020-03-27 20:34:15.484 [INFO ] DispatcherServlet 547 - Completed initialization in 12 ms

20:34:22,454 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 2020-03-27 20:34:22.453 [INFO ] HelloCountryServlet 35 - Logger is running

20:34:22,454 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 2020-03-27 20:34:22.454 [INFO ] HelloCountryServlet 36 - demoProperty :: null

20:34:22,464 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) 2020-03-27 20:34:22.458 [ERROR] ErrorPageFilter 183 - Forwarding to error page from request [/country] due to exception [null]

20:34:22,464 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) java.lang.NullPointerException: null

20:34:22,464 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at com.test.servlets.HelloCountryServlet.doGet(HelloCountryServlet.java:38) ~[classes:?]

20:34:22,464 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1)    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:503) ~[jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar!/:2.0.0.Final]
```

I've been using these links as reference:
https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/

http://www.jcombat.com/spring/how-to-read-properties-using-spring-boot-configurationproperties

Could someone mind assisting me a bit. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems your servlet class is not annotated with Service/Component/Bean.

Comment: @AhmetOZKESEK - looking at the logs above, it is for sure that the servlet class is getting executed. I don't think there is any issue with the Servlet class.

Comment: @dhana1310 - Quite true. there is no issue with the servlet

Comment: `HelloCountryServlet` is not a Spring managed bean and dependency injection didn't happen. Annotate the class with `@Controller` , provide correct http method mapping and retry. You are not using Spring MVC which is the reason for NPE

Comment: @R.G - I did as you suggested, but now getting `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'helloCountryServlet': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'demoProperty'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'property.DemoProperty' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`. Am a missing something here?

Comment: Annotate your `DemoProperty ` with `@Component`

Comment: Please refere examples for MVC [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) and ConfigurationProperties [here](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `@Component` annotation on your DemoProperty Class. Currently it is not considered as bean during the application startup.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. We had a power outage. I already tried that one but to no avail.

Comment: Can I ask a doubt. Is it mandatory to autowire the DemoProperty class inside a @RestController class?

Comment: The reference links all suggested it that way

Comment: @Aron There are 3 ways of Dependency injections in spring, 1.Field level(you are using this), 2. Constructor level and 3. Setter level. Field Level is not the preferred way though.